# Swift 3 - function in viewdidload not completly executing

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, viewdidload

I have used a function in `viewDidLoad` that appends an array and that array is used in other function.But when i execute my program the function in `viewDidLoad` does not completely executing so my `array` remains empty.Please help me for this.

My code:-

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.getAllUsers()
    self.fetchData()
}
 func getAllUsers(){
    ref = Database.database().reference()
    ref.child("users").observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
        if let result = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot] {
            for child in result {
                var userid = child.key
                print(userid)
                self.uuid.append(userid)
            }
        }
        if self.uuid.contains((Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid)!) {
            print("Id matched")
        }
    })

    let array = ["Frodo", "sam", "wise", "gamgee"]
    let randomIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(array.count)))
    print(array[randomIndex])

}
 func fetchData() {
    let randomIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(uuid.count)))
    print(uuid[randomIndex])
    print(randomIndex)
    randomI = randomIndex
    Message.downloadAllMessages(forUserID: uuid[randomIndex], completion: {[weak weakSelf = self] (message) in
        weakSelf?.items.append(message)
        weakSelf?.items.sort{ $0.timestamp < $1.timestamp }
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if let state = weakSelf?.items.isEmpty, state == false {
                weakSelf?.tableView.reloadData()
                weakSelf?.tableView.scrollToRow(at: IndexPath.init(row: self.items.count - 1, section: 0), at: .bottom, animated: false)
            }
        }
    })
    Message.markMessagesRead(forUserID: uuid[randomIndex])
}
```

Comment: show what have you tried.

Comment: show the viewDidLoad() operation.

Comment: can you show us your full code?

Comment: Try to ask with the code don't post without showing your tries.

Comment: check my updated question

Comment: @YashR have you put break points and checked the flow?

Comment: @TusharSharma i have done but it direct access `fetchData()`

Comment: @YashR you mean it never goes inside getAlluser() ??

Comment: @TusharSharma yes it goes inside but it does not goes inside `ref.child("users").observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to call `self.fetchData()` after completion block. You are calling `self.fetchData()`before compeletion.

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.getAllUsers()

}
 func getAllUsers(){
    ref = Database.database().reference()
    ref.child("users").observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
        if let result = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot] {
            for child in result {
                var userid = child.key
                print(userid)
                self.uuid.append(userid)
            }
        }

        if self.uuid.contains((Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid)!) {
            print("Id matched")
        }
        self.fetchData()// call your method after compeletion block
    })

    let array = ["Frodo", "sam", "wise", "gamgee"]
    let randomIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(array.count)))
    print(array[randomIndex])

}
 func fetchData() {
    let randomIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(uuid.count)))
    print(uuid[randomIndex])
    print(randomIndex)
    randomI = randomIndex
    Message.downloadAllMessages(forUserID: uuid[randomIndex], completion: {[weak weakSelf = self] (message) in
        weakSelf?.items.append(message)
        weakSelf?.items.sort{ $0.timestamp < $1.timestamp }
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if let state = weakSelf?.items.isEmpty, state == false {
                weakSelf?.tableView.reloadData()
                weakSelf?.tableView.scrollToRow(at: IndexPath.init(row: self.items.count - 1, section: 0), at: .bottom, animated: false)
            }
        }
    })
    Message.markMessagesRead(forUserID: uuid[randomIndex])
}
```